# Detect a key pressed within a while Python

Tags: python

I want to detect a key pressed in python without using "with", because I want it to show a text in a while

all this with the pynput library:

```
    import time
    from pynput import keyboard
    i = 0
    while True:
        if event.key == keyboard.Key.esc:
            break
        else:
            if a == "hello":
                print("y")
            else:
                print("n")
        if i % 2 = 0:
            a = "hello"   
        else
            a = "good bye"
        i += 1
        print(a)
        time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: without using "with"?

Comment: What is your question? Presumably there is some problem with the code that you posted, but you haven't said what that problem is.

Comment: @JohnColeman the code does not work because I need a with instead of the while

Comment: @Luke because when trying I have to press a key so that it starts showing me the variable a, and it doesn't want to do it constantly only when I press the key

Comment: @Luke Now if I try to put the with inside the while it does the same, it waits for a key and it does not come out there, that is, it does not change the variable to

Answer (score 1):

pynput's `Events` blocks by default.  You can `.get` to limit how long it blocks for:

```
from pynput import keyboard
import time

i = 0
a = "start"
while True:
    if a == "hello":
        print("y")
    else:
        print("n")

    if i % 2 == 0:
        a = "hello"   
    else:
        a = "good bye"

    i += 1
    print(a)

    # Not needed anymore, we're going to block waiting for key events for 2 seconds
    # time.sleep(2)
    with keyboard.Events() as events:
        # Block at most for two seconds
        event = events.get(2.0)
        if event is not None:
            if event.key == keyboard.Key.esc:
                break
```

This won't necessarily always block for two seconds if the user presses some other key.  You can either add code to check for that condition and keep calling `events.get` till enough time has passed, or use `keyboard.Listener` to react to events in real time.

Comment: Since what I'm trying to do is use the time library and specifically sleep, will it be possible to change it to use sleep?

Comment: and I also want that when I press just to print "y" or "n", and not while executing